# Mysql stored procedure return null

Tags: база-данных, sql, mysql

Использую MySQL Workbench.
Создаю простейшую хранимую процедуру таким кодом:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `selectCountry`(IN continent CHAR(13))
BEGIN
    SELECT @continent;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Она успешно создаётся.

Запускаю так:

```
call DB_IF32G.selectCountry('Asia');
```

Но возвращается `NULL`:

[image]

Так в чём же проблема?

Comment: Замените на это:

    SELECT continent;

Comment: @smackmychi, там изначально другой запрос был (на указанной части света он находил страну с наибольшей популяцией). Он должен был работать, а выводил NULL. Я пытался посмотреть, что же вместо continent приходит, а он выдаёт NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте [доки](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

В примерах нет `@`, как передали, так и используете, поэтому правильно будет так:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `selectCountry`(IN continent CHAR(13))
BEGIN
    SELECT continent;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @BOPOH, Ух ты, даже исходный запрос заработал. СПАСИБО

Answer (score 0):

попробуй IN continent VARCHAR(13)

Comment: @vaddemgen, как вы думаете, почему так получилось?

А что покажет следующий код:

    SELECT @a := COUNT(1), @a - 1 AS what FROM table

в what? Не угадали, первый запуск - null, второй - нужное значение (и то - если количество строк в таблице не увеличилось).

Так и здесь, вы, наверное, у себя использовали какую-то другую версию процедуры и ваш запрос возвращал предыдущее значение, помещенное в `@a`

Comment: @Ale_x, эмъ... я, наверное, промазал )) Или ТС здесь писал? )